# How to sign update.zip

Tags: java, android, certificate, recovery, ota

I'm currently trying to apply an update over the stock android recovery. I created the zip contents and my own keys for the android build but it failes with a signature verification error. I have now found this piece of code in the `bootable/recovery/verifier.cpp`

```
#define FOOTER_SIZE 6

if (fseek(f, -FOOTER_SIZE, SEEK_END) != 0) {
    LOGE("failed to seek in %s (%s)\n", path, strerror(errno));
    fclose(f);
    return VERIFY_FAILURE;
}

unsigned char footer[FOOTER_SIZE];
if (fread(footer, 1, FOOTER_SIZE, f) != FOOTER_SIZE) {
    LOGE("failed to read footer from %s (%s)\n", path, strerror(errno));
    fclose(f);
    return VERIFY_FAILURE;
}

if (footer[2] != 0xff || footer[3] != 0xff) {
    LOGE("failed check of footer bytes 2 & 3 match 0xff");
    fclose(f);
    return VERIFY_FAILURE;
}
```

Which expects the 4th and 3rd last byte in the zip to be `0xff`. The verification failes at this point. If I open the zip with a HexEditor I can see that both bytes are not `0xff`. 
If I open a zip from the `/bootable/recovery/testdata/otasigned*.zip` I can see that they are `0xff`.

I signed the zip with following command: `jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java -jar Android/prebuilts/sdk/tools/lib/signapk.jar Android/build/target/product/security/testkey.x509.pem Android/build/target/product/security/testkey.pk8 testupdate.zip update.zip` wich adds some certificate data in the `META-INF` folder.

I couldn't find any information that theese bytes have to be `oxff` on the zip spec either.

What is going wrong here?

PS: Of course i *could* disable signature verification, but I want this feature (only working, not failing ;) )

Comment: Ok, now I know I forgot the -w parameter for SignApk.jar. But now it failes with:

I:1 key(s) loaded from /res/keys
Verifying update package...
I:comment is 1691 bytes; signature 1673 bytes from end
E:failed to verify whole-file signature

But I use the testkey from /build/target/product/secutity wich is also used by the otapackage build rule and the zip build there gets verified correctly... Any explanation for this?

Comment: What do you mean by the '-w' parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use -w option which make signapk sign the whole file

signapk **-w** $KEY_FILE.x509.pem $KEY_FILE.pk8 $UPDATE_ZIP $UPDATE_ZIP.signed

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to modify the code, just use *toggle signature verification* function from your recovery menu to disable the signature check, your update.zip will work

Comment: As I mentioned I don't want to disable signature verifiaction, furthermore there is no menu item to disable it, it is the STOCK Recovery from google